# FileReader(compound Path) causes File not found

Tags: android, filereader

I don't want to spread my app's files over various directories, so I assembled all my files in the directory, where my database is stored, this means in the path that returns the function myContext.getDatabasePath.

So I need to compound the file path by this function's and the file's name like this

```
private void getStatement(int StatementNo) throws Exception {
    String DB_PATH;
    BufferedReader BRdr;
    FileReader FRdr;

    switch(StatementNo){
        case 1:
            SQLstatementNameString = "viewmain.sql";
        case 2:
            SQLstatementNameString = "schonzeit.sql";
        case 3:
            SQLstatementNameString = "fangtb.sql";
        case 5:
            SQLstatementNameString = "sqliteversion.sql";
    }

    try {
        DB_PATH = myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getParent() +  File.separator + SQLstatementNameString;
        FRdr = new FileReader(DB_PATH); //causes file not found error
        BRdr = new BufferedReader(FRdr);
    } catch (Exception eronymus) {
        throw new Exception(eronymus.getMessage());
    }

    BRdr.read(SQLstringAr, 0, 1024);
}
```

I am absolutely sure to have a by android studio directory "databases" created in my app-directory-system and to have there stored all the files returned by the case-structure above, I see this in the project-window in android studio, nevertheless I get a file not found error, calling the "FileReader"-function and don't see the reason.

Comment: "I see this in the project-window in android studio" -- that is showing you files on your development machine, not on the Android device.

Comment: Could you post the exact detail message in the thrown Exception? Acc to docs, the `FileNotFoundException` may be thrown "if the named file does not exist, is a directory rather than a regular file, or for some other reason cannot be opened for reading."

Comment: Hi Gamer007, the message is "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/wolfgang_jakobi.anglerapp/databases/sqliteversion.sql: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)".

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, I'm aware of this point, but I assume that all these directories and files will be part of the apk and installed on the virtual Android Device, this is the fact, at least, with my database stored in the same directory, because I can open it before executing the above code. Did you mean, that this doesn't happen to other files in the databases directory?

Comment: I replaced my first line in the try-block by another FILE-constructor:

Comment: FILE(myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getParent(), SQLstatementNameString);

Comment: Hi overthere, my idea, to assemble all needed files in one directory I gave up, because evidently it contradicts to the philosophy of Java/Android/Google, from the directory "databases" android studio includes just the database files and non of the others, the "files"-directory is intended for read/write-files, while the "assets"-directory is intended for read-only-files, and this is what I needed in my particular case. My files contain different SQL-statements, which I don't want to be changed by my app or by the user.

Comment: private void getStatement(int StatementNo) throws Exception {
            InputStream InpStream;
            switch(StatementNo){
                case 1:
                    SQLstatementNameString = "viewmain.sql";
                case 2:
                    SQLstatementNameString = "schonzeit.sql";
                case 3:
                    SQLstatementNameString = "fangtb.sql";
                case 5:
                    SQLstatementNameString = "sqliteversion.sql";
            }

Comment: try {
            InpStream = myContext.getAssets().open(SQLstatementNameString);
            int size = InpStream.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            InpStream.read(buffer);
            InpStream.close();
            SQLstatement = new String(buffer);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException eronymus) {
            throw new Exception(eronymus.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception eronymus2) {
            throw new Exception(eronymus2.getMessage());
        }
    }

Comment: In other context I was asked, why I sourced the SQL-string out, very easy, I don't want to blow up my source code with relatively static texts, but easy find my SQL-statements to change if it is necessary. Greetings Wolfgang